# Можно ли взывать useEffect() при каждом вызове dispatch?

Tags: reactjs

Я пробовал использовать такой код в компоненте:

```
const {isLoaded, officers } = useSelector(state => state.officers)

const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('dispatch')
},[dispatch])
    
const deleteOfficer = (id) => {
   dispatch(deleteOfficer(id));
}
```

При вызове deleteOfficer идет обращение к функции, которая возращает dispatch:

```
export const deleteOfficer = (id) => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.delete(url + id, headers)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    dispatch(setMessage({
                        success: true,
                        text: `Сотрудник успешно удален`
                    }))
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("error: ", error)
                dispatch(setMessage({
                    success: false,
                    text: `${error.response.data.message}`
                }))
            })
    }
}
```

Изменение state через setMessage() никак не отслеживается в компоненте. Можно ли как-то при вызове dispatch(setMessage()) делать вызов useEffect()?

Comment: `useEffect` срабатывает при каждом рендере, при котором изменились его зависимости.

Comment: @Grundy получается, если функция не изменяет state, то обработать ее вызов в useEffect нельзя?

Comment: что значит _функция не изменяет state_? что значить _обработать вызов в useEffect_?

Comment: Функции setNoLoadedOfficers, getAllOfficers записывают данные redux state, функция deleteOfficer - нет.

Comment: Создайте функцию обертку, которая будет менять состояние компонента и тригерить вызов useEffect. Новую переменную состояния сделайте числом в виде обычного счетчика.

Comment: deleteOfficer вызывает dispatch который вызывает render компонента. Что у тебя внутри обработки этой команды происходит - неизвестно. Сделай [mcve] который можно запустить и увидеть проблему. Пока не понятно что именно не так работает сейчас и как ты хочешь чтобы было

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: что делает setMessage? почему ты думаешь, что useEffect не вызывается?